# Alexa Skill renders display card in Alexa companion app

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

[image]
How To add an image to this card or how remove it totally?

Answer (score -1):

**How to add an image to Alexa Card ?**

Form the official documentation(https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/include-a-card-in-your-skills-response.html#creating-a-basic-home-card-to-display-text)

> A home card can include a single image. In this case, you provide the
>   title, text, and two URLs (a small version and large version) for the
>   image to display.
>
> Note that the total number of characters (title, content, and both
>   URLs combined) for the card cannot exceed 8000. Each URL cannot exceed
>   2000 characters.
>
> To create a card with an image, include the card property in your JSON
>   response:
>
> Set the type to Standard. Set the title and text properties to the
>   text to display. Note that this type of card uses a text property, not
>   a content property like Simple. Use either "\r\n" or "\n" within the
>   text to insert line breaks. Include an image object with smallImageUrl
>   and largeImageUrl properties. Set smallImageUrl and largeImageUrl to
>   the URLs of a small and large version of the image to display. See
>   below for details about the image format, size, and hosting
>   requirements.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {"type":"PlainText","text":"Your Car-Fu car is on the way!"},
    "card": {
      "type": "Standard",
      "title": "Ordering a Car",
      "text": "Your ride is on the way to 123 Main Street!\nEstimated cost for this ride: $25",
      "image": {
        "smallImageUrl": "https://carfu.com/resources/card-images/race-car-small.png",
        "largeImageUrl": "https://carfu.com/resources/card-images/race-car-large.png"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> When using the Java library:
>
> Create a StandardCard object. Call the object's setTitle() and
>   setText() methods to set the title and content. Create an Image object
>   and assign the URLs with the object's setSmallImageUrl() and
>   setLargeImageUrl() methods. Pass the Image object to the StandardCard
>   object with the setImage() method. Pass the StandardCard object to
>   either SpeechletResponse.newTellResponse() or
>   SpeechletResponse.newAskResponse() to get a SpeechletResponse that
>   includes the card.